# SelectOneMenu não trás a descrição do objeto na edição

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

Estou realizando um cadastro que possui um relacionamento com outro, estou usando o SelecOneMenu para traze-lo, ao realizar um novo funciona tudo corretamente, porém na edição ele não está trazendo o objeto da outra classe, e quando eu acabo de salvar um cadastro e tento editar ele trás o objeto, mas é só atualizar a página que não trás mais, os outros campos de texto, trás normalmente.

public void atualizarInterface() {

```
    try {

        Sistema sistema = new Sistema();
        SistemaDao sistemaDao = new SistemaDao();
        sistema = sistemaDao.buscaPorId(idSistema);

        InterfaceDao interfaceDao = new InterfaceDao();
        interfaceSistema.setSistema(sistema);
        interfaceDao.atualizar(interfaceSistema);

        String msg = "Interface " + interfaceSistema.getDescricao() + " Alterada com sucesso";

        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, msg, msg);
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        context.addMessage(null, message);

    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Erro ao atualizar a interface no Bean");
    } finally {
        listarInterface();
    }
}
```

public void selecionarInterface(ActionEvent evento) {

```
    interfaceSistema = (Interface) evento.getComponent().getAttributes().get("interfaceSelecionado");
```

Comment: <p:selectOneMenu filter="true" value="#{interfaceBean.idSistema}">
                                            <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="Selecione um Sistema"/>
                                            <f:selectItems value="#{interfaceBean.listarSistema()}" var="sistema"
                                                           itemValue="#{sistema.id}" itemLabel="#{sistema.descricao}"/>
                                        </p:selectOneMenu>

Comment: Já tentou popular a lista do SelectOneMenu ao editar ?